# fseek. Время работы

Tags: c++, c, golang, файловая-система, любой-язык

Привет.
У меня стоит задача осуществлять многократное перемещение по файлу. Мне важна скорость доступа в связи с этим у меня возникает вопрос о том, как реализована функция fseek или её аналоги. Я не привязываюсь к конкретному языку, так как полагаю, что она реализована везде примерно одинаково. Но если это не так, то речь идёт о golang 1.6 (1.8, если хотите).

Так, например, я нахожусь в начале файла, скажем на нулевом байте. Мне необходимо прочитать последний байт файла. Можно ли оценить время доступа к последнему байту файла по сравнению с временем доступа к первому байту.

Спасибо за помощь.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38024736/how-to-estimate-the-seek-speed-in-file-system

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Никак не можно. fseek лишь меняет переменные в памяти, и *гипотетически* подсказывает механизму кэширования ОС, что файл в дальнейшем будут читать вот с этого места.

Современные ОС в части доступа к файлу настолько сложны (из-за многоуровневого кэша и механизма подкачки в частности), что говорить о времени доступа можно только "в среднем", статистически.

Понятно, что наиболее быстро работа с файлом происходит, когда файл находится на отдельном диске, не фрагментирован, и обрабатывается последовательно крупными блоками.

Добиться такого счастья в реально действующей вычислительной среде малореально.

Comment: Т.е. предугадать, как будет происходить чтение из файла практически невозможно, а значит особым образом формировать файл тоже имеет смысла не очень много? Т.е. формировать его (файл) так, чтобы чтение нескольких байтов производилось из одного и того же места.

Comment: @hedgehogues а какого размера файл мы рассматриваем?

Comment: Порядка 17 гигов